# Crear un escritorio en c++

Tags: c++

Hola estoy intentando crear un escritorio del siguiente modo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include "Windows.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Rpcrt4")


#define  RAND_DESK_NAME  0x000040

template <class TCHAR>
class MakeNewDesktop
{
public:

    MakeNewDesktop();
    bool generateUUID(LPVOID buffer, DWORD sz);
    bool setDeskName(TCHAR *name);
    void SwitchToNew();
    void SwitchToDefault() const;
private:
    bool Create();

public:

private:
    TCHAR DeskName[40];
    int randName;
    bool b_ok;
    UUID bUuid;
    RPC_WSTR rstrUUID;
    HDESK hDeskNew;
    HDESK hDeskOld;

protected:
};


template <class TCHAR>
MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::MakeNewDesktop() : randName(0), rstrUUID(nullptr), hDeskNew(nullptr),
hDeskOld(nullptr), b_ok(false)
{
}


template <class TCHAR>
bool MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::generateUUID(LPVOID buffer, DWORD sz)
{
    // vamos a Generar El Indentificador  Universal unico
    if (UuidCreate(&bUuid) == RPC_S_OK) b_ok = true;
    else return false;

    if (b_ok != false && UuidToStringW(&bUuid, &rstrUUID) == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        // copiamos el numero de caracteres que requiere el buffer
        lstrcpynW(LPWSTR(buffer), LPCWSTR(rstrUUID), sz);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template <class TCHAR>
bool MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::setDeskName(TCHAR* name)
{
    if (name == NULL || ua_lstrlenW(name) > 40) return false;
    else  lstrcpynW(DeskName, name, lstrlenW(name) + 1);
    return true;
}

template <class TCHAR>
bool MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::Create()
{

    b_ok = false;
    if (randName != false || DeskName == FALSE)
        generateUUID(DeskName, 40);

    if (DeskName != NULL && hDeskNew == NULL)
    {
        hDeskOld = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId()); // obtenemos el manejdor de el escritorio actual
        hDeskNew = CreateDesktopW(DeskName, NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL); // creamos el nuevo
        if (hDeskOld != NULL && hDeskNew != NULL)
        {
            WCHAR  explore[MAX_PATH];
            ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%windir%\\explorer.exe", explore, MAX_PATH - 1);
            STARTUPINFOW startup_info = { 0 };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };

            if (SetThreadDesktop(hDeskNew))
            {
                startup_info.cb = sizeof(startup_info);
                startup_info.lpDesktop = DeskName;
                CreateProcessW(explore, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &process_info);
                SetThreadDesktop(hDeskOld);
            }
        }

        b_ok = true;
    }

    return  b_ok;
}

template <class TCHAR>
void MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::SwitchToNew()
{

    if ((Create() != NULL))
    {
        SetThreadDesktop(hDeskNew);
        SwitchDesktop(hDeskNew);

    }

}

template <class TCHAR>
void MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::SwitchToDefault() const
{
    SwitchDesktop(hDeskOld);
    CloseHandle(hDeskNew);
}

typedef  MakeNewDesktop<wchar_t> MakeDeskW;

int main()
{
    MakeDeskW newDesk;
    newDesk.setDeskName(L"Selene-PC");
    newDesk.SwitchToNew();
    Sleep(9000);
    newDesk.SwitchToDefault();
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo siempre me devuelve los mismos errores:

> ||=== Build: Debug in desktop (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|5|warning: ignoring #pragma comment
>   [-Wunknown-pragmas]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|warning: identifier 'nullptr' is a
>   keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|30|error: 'RPC_WSTR' does not name a
>   type|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In constructor
>   'MakeNewDesktop::MakeNewDesktop()':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|error: class 'MakeNewDesktop'
>   does not have any field named 'rstrUUID'|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in
>   this scope|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In member function 'bool
>   MakeNewDesktop::generateUUID(LPVOID, DWORD)':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|52|error: 'rstrUUID' was not declared
>   in this scope|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|129|warning: deprecated conversion from
>   string constant to 'wchar_t*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In instantiation of
>   'MakeNewDesktop::MakeNewDesktop() [with TCHAR = wchar_t]':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|128|required from here| C:\Users\
>   \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|32|warning: 'MakeNewDesktop::hDeskOld'
>   will be initialized after [-Wreorder]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|28|warning:   'bool
>   MakeNewDesktop::b_ok' [-Wreorder]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|warning:   when initialized here
>   [-Wreorder]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In instantiation of
>   'bool MakeNewDesktop::setDeskName(TCHAR*) [with TCHAR = wchar_t]':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|129|required from here|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|65|error: 'ua_lstrlenW' was not
>   declared in this scope|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In instantiation of 'void
>   MakeNewDesktop::SwitchToNew() [with TCHAR = wchar_t]':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|130|required from here|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|108|warning: NULL used in arithmetic
>   [-Wpointer-arith]|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 13 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
>   ===|

Como podría solucionar esto ya que no entiendo bien puesto que he seguido las indicaciones y debería funcionar.

Comment: Parece talmente que te faltan cabeceras por incluir.

Answer (score 4):

Los errores son claros como el cristal, tal vez tengas problemas para entenderlos por estar en inglés, permíteme traducirlos:

> ```
> 'RPC_WSTR' does not name a type
> ```

> ```
> 'RPC_WSTR' no nombra un tipo
> ```

Es decir, tu compilador no sabe lo que es `RPC_WSTR`. Mi amigo Google me ha ayudado a averiguar que `RPC_WSTR` es un tipo que almacena una cadena de caracteres anchos (**W**ide **STR**ing) identificando una llamada a un proceso remoto (**R**emote **P**rocedure **C**all). Si el compilador no encuentra el tipo es posible que te falten cabeceras por incluir; ésta podría ser `"Rpcdce.h"` que está incluida en `"Rpc.h"` (y ésta última es la que Microsoft aconseja incluir).

Aunque en 2006 alguien se quejaba de lo mismo y le [respondieron en MSDN que parecía un bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1b4550a-407b-4c09-8560-0ab9ef6ff754/error-while-compiling-c2664?forum=vclanguage):

> Sospecho que esto es un bug en las cabeceras del kit de desarrollo.
>
> ```
> typedef __nullterminated unsigned short __RPC_FAR *RPC_WSTR;
> ```
>
> Debería ser:
>
> ```
> typedef __nullterminated wchar_t __RPC_FAR *RPC_WSTR;
> ```
>
> `UuidToStringW` usa `RPC_WSTR`.

Si lo que dicen es cierto, no uses `RPC_WSTR` y crea tu propio alias con la forma adecuada.

---

> ```
> class 'MakeNewDesktop' does not have any field named 'rstrUUID'
> ```

> ```
> la clase 'MakeNewDesktop' no dispone de ningún campo llamado 'rstrUUID'
> ```

Dado que el compilador no sabe lo que es `RPC_WSTR` no puede declarar variables usando ese tipo y... no las tiene en cuenta.

---

> ```
> 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
> ```

> ```
> 'nullptr' no ha sido declarado en este ámbito
> ```

Esto está relacionado con una alarma que obtienes anteriormente:

> ```
> identifier 'nullptr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]
> ```

> ```
> el identificador 'nullptr' es una palabra clave en C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]
> ```

Estás usando utilidades de C++11 sin decirle al compilador que las quieres usar (seguramente tu compilador es antiguo) debes añadir en los parámetros del compilador la bandera `-Wc++0x-compat`.

---

> ```
> 'rstrUUID' was not declared in this scope
> ```

> ```
> 'rstrUUID' no ha sido declarado en este ámbito
> ```

Dado que el compilador no sabe lo que es `RPC_WSTR` no puede declarar variables usando ese tipo y... no las tiene en cuenta.

---

> ```
> 'ua_lstrlenW' was not declared in this scope
> ```

> ```
> 'ua_lstrlenW' no ha sido declarado en este ámbito
> ```

Es decir, tu compilador no sabe lo que es `ua_lstrlenW`. Si el compilador no encuentra el tipo es posible que te falten cabeceras por incluir, aunque MSDN no parece conocer dicha función, lo más parecido es [`lstrlen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647492(v=vs.85).aspx) perteneciente a `"Winbase.h"` (incluida en `"Windows.h"`). Si es lo que parece que es (una función para saber la longitud de una cadena de caracteres anchos) puedes usar el equivalente de la librería estándar de C++: [`wcslen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcslen).

Answer (score 3):

Los errores no son nada del otro mundo. Una sencilla búsqueda en Internet te ofrecerá suficiente información sobre cualquiera de ellos.

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|5|warning: ignoring #pragma comment [-Wunknown-pragmas]|

**Motivo**

`#pragma comment` es una directiva específica de los compiladores de Microsoft. No forma parte del estándar y no es una directiva reconocida por GCC, por lo que las compilaciones bajo este compilador no se verán afectadas por dicha directiva.

**Solución**

Tienes tres opciones:

1. Quitas la directiva y cargas las librerías usando la sintaxis correspondiente `-L[RUTA] -l[LIBRERIA]`
2. Compilas con msvc (el compilador de Microsoft)
3. Sigues compilando con GCC pero añades el flag `-Wunkown-pragmas` para deshabilitar el aviso.

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|warning: identifier 'nullptr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]|

**Motivo**

`nullptr` es una palabra que apareció en el lenguaje en el estándar C++11. Para los estándares anteriores es algo desconocido y no saben tratarlo. El estándar C++11 data del 2011, por lo que cualquier compilador mínimamente actualizado es capaz de reconocerlo... pero en muchas versiones aun no viene activado por defecto. Tu compilador parece no ser demasiado moderno ya que aun hace referencias a C++0x (esqueje del cual surgió el citado estándar).

**Solución**

Para tener código compatible con estándares anteriores (típicamente C++03 o C++98) tendrás que sustituir `nullptr` por `0` o `NULL` (es indiferente).

Para activar las características de C++11 hay que compilar (caso de GCC) con el flag `-Wc++0x-compat`. En versiones más modernas, también debería funcionar `-std=c++11`.

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|30|error: 'RPC_WSTR' does not name a type|

**Motivo**

El compilador no sabe cómo tratar `RPC_WSTR`. Debido al primer error el compilador no ha cargado la librería `Rpcrt4` por lo que los elementos que ahí se encuentren (clases, símbolos, funciones, ...) no estarán accesibles en tu código.

**Solución**

Cargar la librería en tu proyecto (mira el primer error).

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In constructor 'MakeNewDesktop::MakeNewDesktop()':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|error: class 'MakeNewDesktop' does not have any field named 'rstrUUID'|

**Motivo**

Seguimos con los errores encadenados. Aunque he puesto dos errores juntos se deben tratar como uno solo. La primera línea es una introducción del segundo error.

Debido al error anterior el compilador no sabe qué tipo de miembro es `rstrUUID`, por lo que no sabe cómo manejarlo. Solucionando el error anterior este desaparecerá solo.

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope|

Ya comentado

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In member function 'bool
>   MakeNewDesktop::generateUUID(LPVOID, DWORD)':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|52|error: 'rstrUUID' was not declared
>   in this scope|

Ya comentado

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|129|warning: deprecated conversion from
>   string constant to 'wchar_t*' [-Wwrite-strings]|

**Motivo**

El error se produce en esta línea:

```
newDesk.setDeskName(L"Selene-PC");
```

Y la función luce tal que:

```
template <class TCHAR>
bool MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::setDeskName(TCHAR* name)
```

`L"Selene-PC"` es una constante, es decir, `const wchar_t*` y tu código intenta referenciar esa constante a través de un puntero no constante. Como C++ posee un tipado fuerte el compilador es capaz de detectar esa incongruencia y te muestra el aviso (podrías acabar haciendo una modificación sobre dicho valor constante por error y los resultados no te iban a gustar).

**Solución**

La función debe aceptar un parámetro constante:

```
template <class TCHAR>
bool MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::setDeskName(const TCHAR* name)
```

Nota que `DeskName` tampoco es constante...

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In instantiation of
>   'MakeNewDesktop::MakeNewDesktop() [with TCHAR = wchar_t]':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|128|required from here|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|32|warning: 'MakeNewDesktop::hDeskOld'
>   will be initialized after [-Wreorder]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|28|warning: 'bool MakeNewDesktop::b_ok'
>   [-Wreorder]|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|39|warning: when initialized here
>   [-Wreorder]|

**Motivo**

Las variables miembro de una clase se ubican en posiciones contiguas de memoria. Para aprovechar la localidad de la caché amén de permitir otras optimizaciones se requiere que dichos miembros se inicialicen en un orden determinado y tu las estás mezclando:

```
private:
    TCHAR DeskName[40]; // 1
    int randName;       // 2
    bool b_ok;          // 3
    UUID bUuid;         // 4
    RPC_WSTR rstrUUID;  // 5
    HDESK hDeskNew;     // 6
    HDESK hDeskOld;     // 7

// ...

template <class TCHAR>
MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::MakeNewDesktop() : randName(0), rstrUUID(nullptr), hDeskNew(nullptr), hDeskOld(nullptr), b_ok(false)
//                                          2             5                    6                    7                  3
{
}
```

**Solución**

- Compila con el flag `-Wreorder` para deshabilitar el aviso
- Cambia el orden en el que se inicializan las variables miembro

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In instantiation of 'bool
>   MakeNewDesktop::setDeskName(TCHAR*) [with TCHAR = wchar_t]':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|129|required from here|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|65|error: 'ua_lstrlenW' was not
>   declared in this scope|

**Motivo**

Función desconocida por el compilador. Te falta un include.

**Solución**

Añade el include correspondiente. No te puedo ayudar en este punto porque desconozco de donde viene esa función.

> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp||In instantiation of 'void
>   MakeNewDesktop::SwitchToNew() [with TCHAR = wchar_t]':|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|130|required from here|
>
> C:\Users\ \Desktop\desktop\main.cpp|108|warning: NULL used in arithmetic
>   [-Wpointer-arith]|

**Motivo**

El error se produce en esta línea:

```
if ((Create() != NULL))
```

Siendo la función `Create()` así:

```
template <class TCHAR>
bool MakeNewDesktop<TCHAR>::Create()
```

Es decir, estás comparando un `bool` con un `int` (la macro `NULL` se declara `#define NULL 0`) y ya hemos hablado que C++ se caracteriza por un tipado fuerte.

**Solución**

Sustituye `NULL` por `true` o `false` según proceda.